# disk check error at boot and then GNU GRUB. How do I fix it?

Tags: boot, grub2

When I have booted my machine and choose Ubuntu.  It did a hard drive check and got an error. Then it opened a black screen like a terminal where I can enter commands.

How to fix?

Comment: There's no need to yell ( all caps ).  Also when asking for help you need to be as specific as possible.  Specify exactly what the error was instead of simply stating there was an error, for instance.

Comment: i cant get the error it changing too fast to the black screen. i didn't yell (: just... i forgot the word (:

Answer (score 1):

Try running the command fsck when you get to that part of black screen. If not sure, do an fdisk -l, see what partition is your ubuntu and do a fsck /dev/partition